# Extract matched strings in C++ with regex

Tags: c++, regex, string

I have following test strings.

```
#5=BUILDING('xxxcdccx',#5,$,$,$,#21,$,$,.ELEMENT.,$,$,$);
#6=BUILDING('xxxcdccx',#5,$,$,$,#21,$,$,.ELEMENT.,$,$,$);
#7=BUILDING('xxxcdccx',#5,$,$,$,#21,$,$,.ELEMENT.,$,$,$);
```

I need to extract:

- "#integer" (that always starts at the beginning of the string) from above strings and store it in a variable.
- the string between "(" and ")" from above test string.

Can someone please suggest how I can achieve this in C++ with regex.

I tried following as simple example (it's a loop that processes one line at a time):

```
std::regex e ("\#[:d:]+");
if (std::regex_match(sLine,e)){
   //store it and process it
}
```

output should be:

```
#5

and

'xxxcdccx',#5,$,$,$,#21,$,$,.ELEMENT.,$,$,$ ?? (not sure)
```

Comment: \#[:\d:]+ Try this for grabbing #digit and
(?<=\()(.*?)(?=\)) for grabbing everything between ()

Comment: I don't know of a compiler with full support for std::regex at this point in time

Comment: Thanks, and @NisargShah should I use regex_match of some other function?

Comment: I don't think you need to escape `#` (and if you did you needed 2 `\ `'s). I'm not sure what `[:d:]` is supposed to be, if C++ follows any reasonable regex standard `\\d` means digit. Oh and you should probably use `regex_search` instead.

Comment: [Boost](http://www.boost.org/libs/regex) has some decent regex support.

Comment: You didn't tell us the output of your simple example.

Comment: Edited the question now. With expected output

Comment: How do I store grabbed value in a variable?

Comment: With `regex_search`? Like [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search).

Comment: @Dukeling, or use raw strings.

Answer (score 1):

## Description

This expression will:

- capture the initial `#` and integer
- capture the value between the parentheses

`^(\#\d+).*?\(([^)]*)\)`

[image]

## Example

[Live Demo](http://www.rubular.com/r/uDF3893IdS)

**Sample Text**

```
#5=BUILDING('xxxcdccx',#5,$,$,$,#21,$,$,.ELEMENT.,$,$,$);
#6=BUILDING('xxxcdccx',#5,$,$,$,#21,$,$,.ELEMENT.,$,$,$);
#7=BUILDING('xxxcdccx',#5,$,$,$,#21,$,$,.ELEMENT.,$,$,$);
```

**Capture Groups**

Group 0 gets the entire matched string
Group 1 gets the `#` and integer
Group 2 gets the value between the parentheses

```
[0][0] = #5=BUILDING('xxxcdccx',#5,$,$,$,#21,$,$,.ELEMENT.,$,$,$)
[0][1] = #5
[0][2] = 'xxxcdccx',#5,$,$,$,#21,$,$,.ELEMENT.,$,$,$

[1][0] = #6=BUILDING('xxxcdccx',#5,$,$,$,#21,$,$,.ELEMENT.,$,$,$)
[1][1] = #6
[1][2] = 'xxxcdccx',#5,$,$,$,#21,$,$,.ELEMENT.,$,$,$

[2][0] = #7=BUILDING('xxxcdccx',#5,$,$,$,#21,$,$,.ELEMENT.,$,$,$)
[2][1] = #7
[2][2] = 'xxxcdccx',#5,$,$,$,#21,$,$,.ELEMENT.,$,$,$
```